# Can't unfollow a post from its page

Tags: bug, follow-posts, unfollow

When I press the "Following" button under a post that I am currently following, I get the popup:

> You're no longer following this question

Yet when I refresh or go to the "Following" tab on my user profile, I'm still following the post.

However, if I try to unfollow a post from the "Following" tab, it works fine.

---

This bug happens to me on both iPhone and Windows (on Safari and Google Chrome browsers).

Comment: seems to be a refresh issue... when I come back after leaving the site, it (the following link) is gone...

Comment: MSE Duplicate: [Unfollowing a post by clicking on the \[following\] button does not work with WebKit browsers (all iOS browsers and Mac Safari)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392679/323179)

Comment: Related: [Unfollowing link on posts not working](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426611/1478931)

Comment: @Laurel It happens on Windows, not just iOS and Mac.