# Unfollowing link on posts not working

Tags: bug, follow-posts, unfollow

If I click the "following" link under a question or answer that I have previously followed, the link text changes to "follow" as I expect. However if I refresh the page, the link text has reverted to "following" and I continue to receive inbox updates when the post changes.

Unfollowing via the "Followed Posts" view in my profile seems to work as expected.

Firefox 102.15.1esr on Debian 12.

Comment: Also on MSE: [Find that it fails to unfollow a question sometimes recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393288)

Comment: Also similar (MSO) [Can't unfollow a post from its page on iPhone](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426325/5320906), (MSE) [Unfollowing a post by clicking on the \[following\] button does not work on WebKit browsers (all iOS browsers and Mac Safari)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392679/397555).